# Is Zalvin an Arabic word, and an appropriate Muslim girl name?

Tags: arabic, naming

Today I heard the name of the girl as Aysha Zalvin. I had never heard of this name before. I searched about it on the net, but I did not find a reliable source.  Is it an Arabic word, and what is the meaning of it?

Edit:Aysha zalvin was the name of an Arab princess(It was stated by the family of that girl).

Comment: Can u explain the reason for downvote

Comment: This question is off-topic for this site. "Questions on Muslim culture or behaviour unrelated to the teachings of Islam are off-topic here."

Comment: While it does seem borderline off-topic, the name "Aysha Zalvin" has some Islamic connotations to it.  I think it'd be best to just let the question be answered: it'd hardly be a burden for someone sufficiently familiar with Arabic names.  (It also resembles previous questions [here](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/25171) and [here](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/9923).)

Comment: Is Zalvin a first or last name? on the whole it doesn't sound Arabic (but maybe you used a strange transliteration) so the rule is does it mean something bad is it related to an other deity, if yes than it is not an appropriate name else it is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my knowledge, this is not an Arabic name, at least I've never heard it in any of Arabian countries. Aysha is a female name and that is correct. But Zalvin is a family name and most of the time families name in arab culture refers to male. So if your child is a male then it is acceptable to name him as Zalvin.

Comment: When I asked their family about the name.They said that it was of an Arab princess name.They didn't know the meaning of it

Comment: @user29535 that is helpful information to [edit] into the question (and, ideally, it should have been there in the original version).

Comment: I asked a U'lama, about the name, and he said that it was the name of Arab tribes. @Raad In your answer,did you mean family for tribes.